# Azure MobileServiceClient LoginAsync

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to use the Azure Mobile Service Client to authenticate my app I am building using Xamarin.Android.  My MainActivity has the following code:

```
[Activity(Label = "AppName", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private MobileServiceUser user;
    private MobileServiceClient client;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        client = new MobileServiceClient(Config.AppServiceUrl);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ListOfEquipmentButton).Click += ListOfEquipmentButton_Click;
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonLoginUser).Click += LoginUser;
    }

    private async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {
        var success = false;
        try
        {

            user = await client.LoginAsync(this,
                                           MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, "https://MyAzureWebServiceSite.azurewebsites.net");
            CreateAndShowDialog(string.Format("you are now logged in - {0}",
                user.UserId), "Logged in!");

            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(ex, "Authentication failed");
        }
        return success;
    }

    public async void LoginUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load data only after authentication succeeds.
        if (await Authenticate())
        {
            //Hide the button after authentication succeeds.
            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonLoginUser).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
    }

    void ListOfEquipmentButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ListOfEquipmentActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void CreateAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title)
    {
        CreateAndShowDialog(exception.Message, title);
    }

    private void CreateAndShowDialog(string message, string title)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.Create().Show();
    }
}
```

when I run this and I click the Login Button I put on the layout I get the following:

[image: Web Authenticator Native Browser]
I assume it is trying to load a web page where I can log in using my Azure AD credentials, but I am not getting the login screen.  Are there any ideas?  Is my code FUBAR to get that?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> user = await client.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, "https://MyAzureWebServiceSite.azurewebsites.net");

Based on your code, I assumed that you are using [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) version 4.x.x. At this time, you need to correctly set the `url_scheme_of_your_app`.

- Set `<url_scheme_of_your_app>://easyauth.callback` under the **Allowed External Redirect URLs** via Azure Portal.
- Under `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add the relevant code inside `application` XML element.

Details you could follow [Add authentication to your Xamarin.Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users).

Moreover, you could also try to downgrade `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` package to 3.1.0 without need to set the above settings.